# File upload Rails Custom

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am wondering how can i upload my file. I am have read this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files but not to sure how to read and write the data from the controller? I also read this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-file-uploading.htm but placing them both together confused me. I don't like gem has i don't understand where the coded is stored, and doesn't allow flexibility in term of me able to write code specific to my application. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using the [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/) gem. The documentation is very straight forward and explains each of the steps in the file upload process.

Comment: The problem i have with gem his that i can't modify, i don't even know how to view it, so to me gem his code that is magic, and i can't stand magic code

Comment: Check that link to github, the code is all there. What exactly are you trying to modify? The views, controllers, and models are all your own code in your Rails app. Even with the Paperclip gem, using the power of Ruby, you can still modify and extend Paperclip to your hearts content.